# Angular ngBind with function / complex expression

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, data-binding, ng-bind

I have a single-page Angular purchase form with a variety of options and a running estimated total that displays in various parts of the form. Calculating the estimated total inline is rather complex and difficult to test:

```
<span ng-bind="purchase.itemTotal + selectedInsurance() + selectedShipping()">?</span>
```

I tried to DRY up my views by refactoring into a function on the scope, and specifying `ng-bind` as this function:

```
$scope.estimatedTotal = function() {
  if ($scope.purchase)
    return $scope.purchase.itemTotal + $scope.selectedInsurance() + $scope.selectedShipping();
}
```

The `if` statement is necessary since it sometimes evaluates before the model `$scope.purchase` is populated via Ajax. The problem is that the function returns undefined initially, before the Ajax GET has completed, but then `ngBind` does not re-evaluate it again.

Can I tell `ngBind` to watch for additional model values? Is there another recommended way to refactor complex `ngBind` expressions that plays well with dirty checking?

Comment: `but then ngBind does not re-evaluate it again` --> Check for any error in your console. You are using $http for ajax right?

Comment: I'm using [angular rails resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) to integrate with a Rails app, and this uses `$http` under the hood. Also, the Ajax is only part of the problem, since its also not re-evaluating when the user updates, e.g., `$scope.purchase.itemTotal`.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when you are not using `$http` to make server request because $http takes care of executing the digest cycle once the request is complete and callback is executed.

If you are using `$ajax` and for whatever reason you cannot use `$http` then wherever you are setting the value in the ajax callback you have to wrap that code inside `$scope.$apply` method which will internally call `$scope.$digest` method to update any bindings or watchers.

E.g

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.purchase = //Set the purchase object/value
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm using [angular rails resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) to integrate with a Rails app, and this uses `$http` under the hood. When I try to wrap assignment in `$scope.$apply`, I get an error "$digest already in progress." Also, the Ajax is only part of the problem, since its also not re-evaluating when the user updates, e.g., `$scope.purchase.itemTotal`.

Comment: Sorry, this project was sidelined so it took me awhile to test. When I wrap the assignment in this way, it turns out nothing is assigned, since `$scope.$$phase` is always `"$digest"`.

Comment: And in any case, I'm not just asking about when the value updates via AJAX; I'm also asking about when it updates via user input through `ng-model`, where it doesn't update either.